# Put bold format in Laravel Mail Notifications

Tags: laravel, notifications

I'm using new Laravel Notifications in Laravel 5.3, and I love it!

Now, I need to put a little format in my content, like that:

```
<strong>Name:</strong> My Name <br/>
<strong>City:</strong> NYC <br/>
<strong>Country:</strong>USA <br/>
```

And Tags is not interpreted in the line() method.

I tried to change the default view and publish it, but then all my Notifications view are altered with the new view, I just want to be applied on 1 case....

How should I do it???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to update the notifications view indeed so you are on the right track.

Basically after publishing the notification package's resources doing so:

```
$ php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

All you need to do is open `resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php` and replace the occurrences of `{{ $line }}` with `{!! $line !!}`.

This is just telling Blade not to escape the tags.

Hope this helps!